# parsing the package error

Tags: android, package

I'm new to Android development. I gone through the tutorial and managed to create Hello World program in my Eclipse. I managed to run it and viewed the output in Emulator. I export the project and saved in my local and later moved to my Samsung Galaxy Nexus. I used ASTRO file management to install the file, but I got an error saying 'Parse Error:There is a problem parsing the package'. I googled and most of them asking me to change the file manager to install the project in Samsung Galaxy Nexus. Hope someone can help me on this matter. The phone using and

Comment: please check your manifest file in that make sure minSDK version is not higher than your phone sdk version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its version issue. My target was 4.0.3 mean while my phone was 4.0.2. I changed the target version in my project and its works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should install the apk in the phone and **not** the project.

Comment: Hi. Its version issue. My target was 4.0.3 mean while my phone was 4.0.2. I changed the target version in my project and its works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better connect your device to Pc and run your application to mobile. Before, connecting your mobile it needs some PC suite to support your device for Eclipse. Just download that also. Hope it helps. And, also see these links -

[1) Parsing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android)

[2) Hello World program Parsing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816086/android-hello-world-tutorial-program-error-parse-error-there-is-a-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Have you exported the signed application package and transferred it to your Google Nexus? If so, it should be installed.