# Can you change min. API level for your Android app in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, api

I selected API minimum level 1.5 for my android app and I'm just about to integrate gestures in to it which came in 1.6. Is there a way in Eclipse to change the minimum level from 1.5 to 1.6 halfway through building an app?

Many thanks

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If you go into your Manifest file and set

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

to

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

Then you will have changed your entire project from running 1.5 as a minimum to 1.6.

While you are still building your app, you can change the minimum API level at any time.

Comment: What about for live app? its give error while install app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android

Answer (score 20):

Using Android Studio, you would find `minSdkVersion` in the `build.gradle` file under `app` directory.

Comment: Try to improve your answer.

Answer (score 11):

The answers regarding uses-sdk are no longer true in Intellij.

Now `<uses-sdk>` is ignored in the AndroidManifest.xml, it is automatically added to the built manifest file.  To change the version, go to the 'build.gradle' file and look at the minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, go to your manifest and change `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />` to `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />`. Then go to Project > Properties > Android and change the Project Build Target to 1.6 to recognize new API code introduced in 1.6.

Answer (score 5):

Change the following line in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Just think of minSdkVersion as your targeted API number.

Keep in mind that this could cause some older devices not run your application.

Answer (score 2):

In Intellij version of Android Studio, you can just go to Gradle Scripts>build.gradle(Module:app) then changing this line

> minSdkVersion 12

to the number of version you desire.

Answer (score 0):

*In Android Studio you will find  the minSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion in the build.gradle (module:app)file under the Gradle Scripts Directory. Edit the build version here and then open the Manifest file to Synch the changes made.*