# highlight selected item on listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

**before someone marked this question as duplicate, I must say I already know that this question is already asked several times, but every time I tried I always failed.**

so I have a listview of date on the left and I want to show data on the right, I want to make a listview that can show which item is selected so I know which date that I picked.
So far I've tried this;

on listview I've added `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"`;

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listTglRMPasien"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnObatAlkes"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
</ListView>
```

on item of listview I've added `android:background="@drawable/list_selector"`;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtListRekamMedikTanggal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListRekamMedikTabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and on list_selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

note that ic_launcher and blue here are png file, it's supposed to be "@drawable/listitem_pressed" and "@drawable/solid_white", I find this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742269/android-set-list-view-item-as-selected-highlighted)
but somehow it got an error, it says `No resource found that matches the given name` and I think something is missing so I changed it to png file

anyway, when I tried to run this, it always show `ic_launcher` whether I select it or not, it never show `blue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently it happens because my API level is too low, I changed it from API level 8 to API level 14.

this is a good answer about [how to change min. API level for your Android app in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268055/can-you-change-min-api-level-for-your-android-app-in-eclipse/3268321#3268321)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did on my ListView. Create your own theme on `res/values` folder, you can name it for example mytheme.xml. Here what I added on mytheme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="mytheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
   <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Then in your `Manifest` add this `android:theme="@style/mytheme"` inside the activity of your ListView Class.

Hope it helps.