# Error when  installing my app on the phone

Tags: android

I have a `LG P500` with `Android 2.2` and when I want to install any `.apk` a message appears:

```
 "There is problem parsing package"
```

Comment: how do you install the apk ? Do you use adb ?

Comment: First of all, if you have any previous version of the app, uninstall it then try again. Secondly if your installing using adb, make sure the app supports android 2.2 in the manifest under minSdkVersion. Hope this helps, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be change in .apk names , difference in versions,
check here , 
["Parse Error : There is a problem parsing the package" while installing Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android-a)
Any of those cases you might be encountering

Answer (score 0):

Did you build your .apk using Android 2.2 or earlier? I had the same problem and found that I compiled the .apk using a SDK version (4.0.3) which was greater than the version my phone supported (2.3.4). I rebuilt my application using SDK 2.3.3 (with some porting mods). I was able to install if after doing so.

Comment: Build target has nothing to do with the ability to install and run the app. Generally, you can build your app using any SDK version and you can still install it and run it on older/newer devices.

Answer (score 0):

its possible your device doesn't meet the minimum processor or gpu requirements of the application.

Answer (score 0):

If the device Android OS version is not compatible with the .apk file
Like .apk file is build in minimum sdkversion 15,and sdktarget 17(ICS) and you have device version 2.3 (gingerbread)