# Why the error "Parse Error: There is an issue parsing the package"?

Tags: android, eclipse

My phone is a [Samsung Galaxy S II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II) running Android version 2.3.3, and when I try to install a package I get the error

> Parse Error

I use Android 3.2 to make these packages.

Comment: You answered yourself. If you use 3.2 to package then how could you install this on 2.3.3?

Comment: You can compile with a higher sdk and still target lower devices, the key is to to define the minSdkVersion in the manifest and ensure the compatibility with lower api levels.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You answered yourself,

> My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S II running Android version 2.3.3, and when I try to install a package I get the error "Parse Error". I use Android 3.2 to make these packages.

You are trying to open a 3.2 application on a 2.3.3 device.

**Solution**

1. Change the required API level tag `android:minSdkVersion` from the manifest file
2. or remove the required API level tag `android:minSdkVersion`.

Comment: Just encountered this. I found out that minSDK version in the properties file and manifest file had to be downgraded to a lower version that the mobile phone supports. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

The "There is a problem parsing the package" error could be from several causes, a common one being trying to open a package with an older android version. You say you are building those packages as 3.2 and trying to open them in a 2.3.3, so that's probably it.

Now, if I recall correctly 3.x version is only meant for tablets, but Samsung Galaxy S2 isn't a tablet... or is it?

Comment: it is not a tablet and thanks for the help