# Error when parsing a custom apk file

Tags: android, eclipse, samsung-mobile

I started to look into Android programming today and created a very small app that is supposed to play MP3s. The tools I used where the Android SDK and eclipse. The code executed flawlessly in the Android emulator but after exporting it and attempting to install the apk on my Samsung Galaxy S2 I received a message telling me there was an error when parsing the file.

Here is my phone's configuration: Android v2.3.3, installation from unknown sources = allowed, USB-Debugging = enabled. The target system for my project has been set to Android v2.3.3 as well and the CPU architecture of the AVD has been set to ARM (armeabi).

I signed the apk using a custom keystone when exporting it, as I initially thought the problem might be a debug key which wouldn't work on real devices.

I attempted to install the app using both, the internal file explorer and a custom explorer (ES File Explorer) but it didn't work for.

Suggestions on how to make my phone execute my custom apps would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Did you export it signed or unsigned?

Comment: I assume I exported it signed as the Android documentation states "You can automate the release signing process by using the Eclipse Export Wizard".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, since it's complaining about the .apk file, try opening the .apk file by renaming the extension to .zip. If you can rename the file, and open it normally in Windows Explorer, then that should indicate the file itself isn't corrupt.

Secondly, I would try installing by connecting your device via usb and using the command `adb -d install "path-to-your-apk-file.apk"`. If this doesn't work, hopefully adb will spit out something more descriptive, and you can update your question with the error.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I noticed that apk files are just zip files and I am able to successfully open and view both, the unsigned as well as the signed output.

I can't try the second option because the USB driver doesn't install properly on my system for some reason (Windows 7 Ultimate x64). I tried installing Samsung Kies and the Google USB Drivers but both of them don't seem to work. And "adb devices" only returns the ADV even though my real devices is connected to the computer.

Might try setting the tools up on my Debian OS instead.

Comment: So you say, your USB driver does not work and still expect it to correctly transfer the .apk to your device?

Comment: Hmmm. Finding the right adb drivers is always a nightmare): Why don't you try using this tutorial for the Samsung S2 http://naturalprogression.wordpress.com/2011/07/19/samsung-galaxy-s2-adb-device-driver/ Besides, if you're going to be developing much, you will want to develop on a real device. Uploading, installing, and app performance is so much better on a real device.

Comment: @HeikoRupp The adb drivers are different from the ones used to just transfer files. The file transfer mode just treats the Android as a mass storage device.

Comment: Tried all the steps mentioned on the website you posted, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the parsing error on custom apk files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370447/why-this-error-parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package). Removing the required API level tag **android:minSdkVersion** in **AndroidManifest.xml** solved the problem.