# I used the adb install method for my android phone. I can't find the ap on my phone

Tags: android

I followed a tutorial with adb commands to install an application on my phone, but it is nowhere to be found on my phone.

I used the following command:

`adb install androidapp.apk`

Can someone please help me? It'll be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're compiling and exporting your apk file under SDK version 2.1, it will not work on any android version below your SDK export "2.1". Android software is forward compatible not backward compatible. For example if you're programming using the android NDK (ann add-on to the android SDK) package that allows development in the C/C++ family, this is only compatible with android 2.3, android version 2.2 and below support java builds only. Therefore you will reaceive the "There is a problem parsing the package" error.

Create one new Project and choose AVD with version 2.1 now try to run in both

Comment: I'm installing Android 2.1 from SDK Manager now

Answer (score 0):

**Procedure to install the apk files in Android Emulator(AVD):**

Check your installed directory(ex: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools), whether it has the adb.exe or not). If not present in this folder, then download the attachment [here](http://www.botskool.com/downloads/geeks/android/adb.zip), extract the zip files. You will get adb files, copy and paste those three files inside tools folder

Run AVD manager from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk and start the Android Emulator.

Copy and paste the apk file inside the C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools

- Go to **Start -> Run -> cmd**
- Type **cd “C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools”**
- Type **adb install example.apk**
- After getting **success** command
- Go to Application icon in Android emulator, we can **see the your application**

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Ponmalar,thank you for the quick response.. the adb.exe is already there.

I downloaded the apk file to my phone.. But when I run it, it says 'parse error'

Would you please assit me with this matter?

Comment: can you please give me your apk file to try in my system if you can. I think your application has this parse error. Is that application is running without any error?

Comment: I think you can use http://www.filefactory.com/u/local to upload file. and send me the link

Comment: It is failed to install... please check your application whether it is running without error or not

Comment: it runs in the emulator just fine.

Comment: Is that running fine in both device and emulator?

Comment: Error is not in the Application I think, Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370447/why-the-error-parse-error-there-is-an-issue-parsing-the-package

Comment: I didnt change the name or anything

Comment: Also both my phone and eclipse on android sdk 4.0  :(

Comment: Can u plz upload a hello world apk to that website i want to see if it runs

Comment: Ok ill try that n let u know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

when application run on emulator it creates an .apk file on project/bin folder. you just connect your android phone with usb mass storage and then copy this apk to SD card. it will then install the app on phone by clicking the apk file on phone. Otherwise post your code to check

Comment: I used the extract method to create the apk file

Comment: I'm not aware of this method... Can you please tell me more... While running the project apk file will be created automatically, then why you used this...

Comment: `public class AndroidActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout lin = new LinearLayout(this);
        lin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("Hello World");
        lin.addView(text);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        lin.addView(button);   
        setContentView(lin);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button.setText("Click Here!!");
    }
}`

Comment: Please edit your question with this code... It will be more clear to check

Comment: thats what the tutorial said. Ok i took the file from bin and put it on the storage of my device.. still same error.. heres my code:

Comment: even if i try to put the default android code on it with the helloworldactivity still gives me same error