# problem in installing .apk in android device?

Tags: android, devise

I have developed an application in which used punjabi text.But when i try to install the appliation in my android device which is "**samsung galaxy pop"** .My application doesn't get installed.It shows the message "**There is a problem in parsing the package.**"
Please can anyone help me to resolve the problem.

Thanx in Advance

Comment: Hi Please check below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android-a

Comment: Show us the debug statements generated from 'adb logcat'.

Comment: Can you access the Logcat log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following code in Manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" />
```

Comment: thanx @David , my application has been installed