# Package Parsing Error

Tags: android

I am getting an error "There is problem parsing package" .

I have checked the possible solution like this ["Parse Error : There is a problem parsing the package" while installing Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android).

But in my case its bit different ,when push my apk by USB my app works fine but when i download it from my web server i get this error .

Any suggestion y i am getting this problem ?

Comment: are downloading the apk in your code?

Comment: have you signed the apk..if not then may be both apk generated from different root folders..I mean both have different default keys..So check whether both onlne and offline apk is generated from same source folder

Comment: @Maneesh : I have signed my app with my Key already . Any other suggestion ?

Comment: Please uninstall the app first in device and install fresh from web server...do check same in emulator also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution . Error was due to MIME Type . I have been adding Mime type in aspx file not to IIS server which was causing problem . 
So , finally i have added mime type to IIS sever and my it started working .  :)

Check this link for adding mime type to web server (IIS in mime case) : 
http://www.hosting.com/support/dedicated/IIS/newmime