# parse error when trying to install apps onto my phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having issues trying to put my own apps on my phone. A bit of background information, I'm using the latest version of eclipse IDE, trying to get apps onto my galaxy s. I tried installing apps through gmail. When I go to install the app I get a parse error and it doesn't install. I have also tried using this method to install my app onto a htc wildfire s however I get the same issue. Is there a quick fix for this? Thanks for your time; any insight into what the problem is will be great.

Things I've tried:
Ok I still have a parse error when I try installing my app. The min sdkversion was set to 9 which seems right to me as that is the api level for gingerbread which galaxy s uses (i think). I haven't set a target sdkversion yet as according to the android developer guide it if not stated it defaults to the minsdkversion. I also tried setting the minsdkversion to 1 and still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: PLease look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android

Answer (score 0):

try to check **unknown source** in **settings==>applications** if you are installing  non-market  application..

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I have tried this also however I still get an error. I've looked at a couple of solutions online such as installing astro file manager but the issue still remains

Comment: Ravi Vyas refers to a topic deals with such as issue .. it may be caused because your android version on device or hardware  not match with the requirements in app.. if you are who develop those app, try to install them through eclipse, this will help you to know where is the problem ..

Comment: Hi again, I changed the version code to 2 and version name to 1.0.1 as stated in the other thread however I'm still getting parse errors. I can't seem to install the app through eclipse as I had loads of problems downloading the correct driver then I had a usb malfunction so the device isn't recognised on my pc

Comment: with android version, I meant the version of Android not your own developing version.. go to AndroidManifest.xml and check what version you defined your application to work with ..take a look on this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: Hi again, ok I've changed the android manifest.xml version name to 2.3 as that is what I assume the galaxy s uses and still it gives me this parse error. I guess it will just be a case of changing the version number until I get the right one?

Comment: you cannot put 2.3 as version, its or 9 as integer number .. well I would recommend to create another simple example and try to install it .. if you are able to use dab, write this command to install the app:"dab install PATHFILE" PATHFILE is the full path to your app.

Comment: ah ok so is the versionname in the android manifest the api level for the platform?

Comment: Ok I still have a parse error when I try installing my app. The min sdkversion was set to 9 which seems right to me as that is the api level for gingerbread which galaxy s uses (i think). I haven't set a target sdkversion yet as according to the android developer guide it if not stated it defaults to the minsdkversion. I also tried setting the minsdkversion to 1 and still no luck. Any ideas?