# how to load the .apk file into the real device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

hey friends i m trying to load my .apk file on to the device but it shows an error when i m trying to install it in the phone it says

```
parse error
there is a problem parsing the package
```

i tried exporting the project on to the phone..

and also tried to export it via android tools by right clicking my project in eclipse!!

is there any other alternative way in which i can send my .apk file to the phone and also with the correct packages!!

how can i overcome this???

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Parse Error : There is a problem parsing the package" while installing Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android)

Comment: is there an alternate solution....i just cant go with that one!!!!

Comment: Just try to sign youa apk file and get it into your device. After, try to run. It will surely works. [See this video](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CE0QtwIwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DgpxM0ffAvok&ei=T1TxT-CsPMuJrAeOwZm-DQ&usg=AFQjCNGX4HaJvhhcGd3bJZVeJTEG3pgfkg&sig2=4EZdMYpVAR2azdL0g0klOQ) and [See this existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4853011/940096)

Comment: i did it earlier but it dint help me!!!

Comment: Are you using `eclipse` workspace for android?

Comment: Then, just get the apk file from `bin` folder as per **User : Kevin Adesara** answer

Answer (score 0):

got to terminal/command form and navigate to platform-tools directory.

then type the `./adb install <path of the .apk file>` on linux machine.

```
adb install <path of the .apk file>
```

on windows machine.

Comment: wher should i type the above statement in windows7

Answer (score 0):

You can find .apk file into your project's **bin** folder. You can install that .apk file into real device via **adb** command. Read more about adb [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html).