# Update the app in another machine with same debug.keystore in android

Tags: android, keystore, apk

I have installed my app in my device.Now due to some reasons I have exported my code and debug.keystore to another machine.When I rebuild the app It is saying "Re-installation failed due to different application signatures." Actully I want to update the app without uninstall. How can I do this?

Thanks,Chaitanya

Comment: You can update after change the version code...

Comment: You can replace the `new machine` keystore file with the `old mechine's` keystore file. You can find `keystore` file in your `.android` folder.

Comment: @user3 `You only need to sign the app with the debug keystore` What?? you need production keystore file to upload on the market. Who said `Home base` tests does not need the debug ketstore?

Comment: I dont use the debug keystore to test at work, I just connect my device using the ADB and run the application onto the device direct from eclipse! Simple!

Comment: in that case your eclipse uses the default debug.keystore present in your home directory. You need to find it in your $HOME/.android and replace it in other machine

Comment: @user3 :D When you run application from Eclipse, internally your app gets signed by debug certificate and then get installed on Device... And this is the use of debug certificate :D. Don't confuse your self and SO too

Comment: @user3 read this http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode and before writing anything on SO please confirm it.

Comment: Finally I got the solution by removing bin folder and also I have changed the keystore file with older machine.. Thanks for your valuaable replies

Comment: Okay, thank you folks. I got how it functions. However it was working in my case, without my knowing how :D Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy the previous debug.keystore from your old machine and place it in your different machine.

The location of `debug.keystore` is typically your `.android` directory present inside home directory.

*In Windows, "My Documents" is your home directory and in Linux the default directory to which you new shell opens to is your home directory.*

Comment: It worked for me when only I have deleted the bin folder.once again thanks for all

Comment: Can some one tell me where is the bin folder located.

Comment: Which bin folder is to be deleted.i copied the debug keystore from old to new computer but still get same error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you only need to change the debug keystore of new machine with the one from old machine because when you run the app from compiler its debuged from the debug.keystore from .android folder and then is installed to device/emulator