# How to move android project to another pc?

Tags: android

i want to move my android studio project to another pc but when im moving files from pc one to pc two and i'm trying to run the same app it's not launching and asking to remove old(the same package) app, but i want to save app signature how can i do it? for example i want to work at home, after i'm going to work and continue my project at work is it possible and how? and yes, sorry for my bad english...

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKO1j.png)

Comment: Why don't you use git? How do you transfer your files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i want to save app signature how can i do it?

Each Android Studio installation will generate its own debug keystore for signing a debug apk. Quoting from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode) on app signing:

> "The first time you run or debug your project in Android Studio, the IDE automatically creates the debug keystore and certificate in $HOME/.android/debug.keystore, and sets the keystore and key passwords."

Apps signed with a different debug key are perceived to be different apps. So you need to copy one of the debug keystores to the $HOME/.android/ folder on the other development machine.

Answer (score 0):

Download GitHub desktop and sign up. Then create repository and push project in repository. At the work in Android Studio go to File -> New -> Import Project and past a link to created repository.
https://desktop.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

To see how to transfer the debug.keystore that is required so you don't get the message "The device already has an application with the same application but a different signature.  In order to proceed you will have to uninstall the existing application." (and lose your data). See [Update the app in another machine with same debug.keystore in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266947/update-the-app-in-another-machine-with-same-debug-keystore-in-android)