# android studio INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, keystore, signature

I published a version of my app to market.
My project somehow corrupted.
I started a new project with the `same package-name` and `same key-store`
But when i run the project gives me this error: `INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE`

I think the new APK is generated with different Signature than the published one.

How can i generate APK with the same Signature with the published one?!
Thanks.

Comment: Select the same keystore and keyalias when building the apk file. Anyway google play will not let you upload a update with a different signature...

Comment: I do. but the error appears again.

Comment: I assume you are not using google play?

Comment: I did not upload the apk. you think i should try to upload it? sorry for bad english

Comment: If the signature is different it will not let you upload.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have that app installed on the device on you are trying to run..

This may help:

1. Uninstall App
       adb uninstall package-name
2. Reboot Device (if problem still exists)

   there may be signature difference between the app that is installed on your device and the app you are trying to install.

   more info: [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE when I try to install compiled .apk on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891848/install-failed-update-incompatible-when-i-try-to-install-compiled-apk-on-device)

Comment: Why android studio generates different signature? i use the same key-store. and I think its weird.

Comment: having same signatures we often get this error. may be your signature are not different, you should try to uninstall the app once.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing the app-release.apk on the emulator with drag and drop.

Uninstall the drag and drop app-release.apk version did solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

For me, I had the an android phone connected and also had the emulator running, so the failure was not on the actual device but on the emulator. Should have ready the error message better. Had to close down the emulator for it to work.