# Phonegap Unable to Install the apk file on android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-cli

I have recently got the following error while installing PhoneGap build apk on phone or emulator

```
 pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

Then I found the reason for it is due to signatures of the build app So then I uninstalled my android studio and Updated my Node js. Now I can install it on Emulator but not the phone Still I am getting the same error.

I have already gone through the solution available on the Internet including [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE when I try to install compiled .apk on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891848/install-failed-update-incompatible-when-i-try-to-install-compiled-apk-on-device)

With help of available solutions, I can install in Emulator but not in my when phone and I don't have any previous versions of the app to uninstall the app

Still, I have no clue how to solve this error.

Please help to how to solve it.

Comment: You can uninstall app and reinstall it in yur phone. Maybe it need `uninstalled for all users`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_UPDATE\_INCOMPATIBLE when I try to install compiled .apk on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891848/install-failed-update-incompatible-when-i-try-to-install-compiled-apk-on-device)

Comment: I have already gone through it but I am unsuccessful. And I am  not able to install the app which is new app as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I solved my Problem.

The problem If you have Android Studio, and PhoneGap installed in the same system the Signature key Generated by Android Studio will make your build app by Phonegap,  leads to the problem mentioned above. To solve this one,  Uninstall all the Android studio, Phonegap New Desktop application, and  CLI and reinstall only PhoneGap then the problem is solved.

Hope this helps you.