# xamarin.android project deployment errors

Tags: deployment, xamarin.android

i made a project to try and use admob banner but when i deploy the project on my device (api 21) i get a "there were deployment errors. continue?" massege but when i run it on my emulator(api 23) it works perfectly.
my target android version and target framework version are both set to api 21

this is what i get in the output window

sorry for the length i wasnt sure how much of it to put

```
         :Deployment failed
          2>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
2>   ב-  Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
2>   ב-  Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyE.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
2>   ב-  System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   ב-  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
2>System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyE.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>c__async1.MoveNext()
2>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>c__async0.MoveNext()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
2>   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.InstallPackageAssemblies.Execute()
2>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
2>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
2>---> (Inner Exception #0) Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<InstallPackage>c__AnonStoreyE.<>m__0(Task`1 t)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>c__async1.MoveNext()
2>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>c__async0.MoveNext()<---
2>
2>Build FAILED.
2>
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_UPDATE\_INCOMPATIBLE when I try to install compiled .apk on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891848/install-failed-update-incompatible-when-i-try-to-install-compiled-apk-on-device)

Comment: i tried to delete my guest and deployed again and got the same results