# Google Play APK cannot install on Android Emulator API 25

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play, google-play-services

I am a beginner with Android Studio, and I would like to test out the emulators. I downloaded the recommended version of Android 7.1 System Image (Android 7.1.1, with Google APIs, x86, running on Nexus 5X hardware profile). I am able to install normal programmes like games by just dragging the apk onto the emulator. But when it comes to Google Play Store, I keep getting this error message when trying to install it.

> INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

So I tried with different versions of images, API 25 do not have any google apps except for google chrome and map. API 24 do have most of the google apps, but not google play games, and google play store. Both versions failed to install the play store apk. 
I searched for quite a while, and came to a lot of answers. A lot of them talked about a lot of codes, I tried some of them, including using ADB, but all failed. To be more specific, I tried:

```
adb install ......\......\......\com.android.vending.apk
adb uninstall ......\......\......\com.android vending.apk
```

Both of them failed. **I correctly stated the path for the APK on my computer**. The first command result in

> INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

The second command result in

> DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

So I am pretty confused now. Seems that **a lot** of ways that seemed to be working for others just could not work for my emulator.
I also tried disabling google play services in the settings inside the emulator, the error did not pop up, but it was still installing after 2hours plus.
I tried enabling it again, same error pop up again...
I also tried deleting all the google play-related stuff after I closed the emulator, by using the SDK Tools Manager in the android studio settings. [Settings Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AezkI.png), similarly, the installation took a VERY long time, I had to end it in the end.
I tried reinstalling the system images, reinstalling the google play-related SDK Tools, no use. Ethier that error message, or 2hour+ installation with no ending. Always these two results.
So is there any possible solutions? I can provide more detail if required.
Here is the emulator specifications:

> Name: Nexus_5X_API_25_Android_7.1_x86_Phone
>
> CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
>
> Path:
>   C:\Users\avits_o.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_25_Android_7.1_x86_Phone.avd
>
> Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 25)
>
> Skin: nexus_5x
>
> SD Card:
>   C:\Users\avits_o.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_25_Android_7.1_x86_Phone.avd\sdcard.img
>
> hw.dPad: no
>
> runtime.network.speed: full
>
> hw.accelerometer: yes
>
> hw.device.name: Nexus 5X
>
> vm.heapSize: 64
>
> skin.dynamic: yes
>
> hw.device.manufacturer: Google
>
> hw.gps: yes
>
> hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
>
> image.androidVersion.api: 25
>
> hw.audioInput: yes
>
> image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-25\google_apis\x86\
>
> tag.id: google_apis
>
> showDeviceFrame: yes
>
> hw.camera.back: emulated
>
> hw.mainKeys: no
>
> AvdId: Nexus_5X_API_25_Android_7.1_x86_Phone
>
> hw.camera.front: emulated
>
> hw.lcd.density: 420
>
> avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5X API 25 Android 7.1 x86 Phone
>
> hw.gpu.mode: host
>
> hw.device.hash2: MD5:1be89bc42ec9644d4b77968b23474980
>
> hw.ramSize: 1200
>
> hw.trackBall: no
>
> hw.battery: yes
>
> hw.cpu.ncore: 4
>
> hw.sdCard: yes
>
> tag.display: Google APIs
>
> runtime.network.latency: none
>
> hw.keyboard: yes
>
> hw.sensors.proximity: yes
>
> disk.dataPartition.size: 2000M
>
> hw.sensors.orientation: yes
>
> avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
>
> hw.gpu.enabled: yes

Also, the android studio has **just been** updated to 2.3 (as at 14 March 2017). Before or after the update, same problems occurs.
By the way, my **ultimate** goal of doing it is to install and use Google Play Games on my device. When I tried installing APK of Google Play Games, it will show [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crMgL.png) :

> INSTALL FAILED DUPLICATE PERMISSION

So it also cannot be installed......
Thanks for any form of help!

Comment: Based from this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891848/install-failed-update-incompatible-when-i-try-to-install-compiled-apk-on-device), maybe the application which you want to install is already installed. Remove the old one and try again. Go into `Settings` -> `Manage Applications` to find the app and choose to Uninstall it. Also, this might happen because your debug version is signed with a different key than the release version. Check it [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8501/install-failed-update-incompatible).

Comment: @abielita I could not find this thing called "Google Play Store" in the settings-apps. Instead, there is only "Google Play services" which cannot be uninstalled but only disabled. I tried disabling it, it will result in endless installation of Play Store, as mentioned in my question. I will check out the links in your comment, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the the latest emulator images for API 24 or API 26. They now include the Google Play store already preinstalled.  API 25 does not have the Google Play store app yet. See the screenshot from the Android Studio 2.4+ AVD Manager.

[image: Android Studio 3.0 AVD Manager]

The Google play store app is a system app with many versions, which means many things can go wrong when trying to manually install it. With the Google Play store built-in to the emulator system images you will not have to worry about this.

See this official announcement about the inclusion of the Google Play store added to the Android Emulator:  https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-3-0-canary1.html

Comment: Thank you. I have already known that Google added Play Store into their emulator. Thanks anyway.