# Getting install_failed_update_incompatible app not installed

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting this error when I try to update my app  from V1.0 to V2.0. Both the versions are debug variant.

Comment: So what did you change from V1 to V2? Did you edit your DB? did you deploy your V1 form a different laptop than the one you are using now? What is the error given after this incompatible error. Does it explain why its not compatible?

Comment: Getting this message "Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing."

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the old one from your device first and then run again.

Comment: this will help in installation but won't tell what is the issue to OP for preventing it next time.

Comment: Any other solution without uninstalling the previous version. I need to retain the data from the previous version.

Comment: have you changed the versioncode along with your version name ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891848/install-failed-update-incompatible-when-i-try-to-install-compiled-apk-on-device

Comment: Try changing the version code to a higher number. Let me know so I can update my answer.

Comment: Tried but no use