# when try update my app I get error: Failure INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, adb

**Android 6.0**

In my app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    flavorDimensions "default"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 60
        versionName "3.4"
```

Install from Google play my version (old version).
Then  I want to test update my sign app by new version of my app (sign apk) like this:

```
android adb install -r my_app-release.apk
```

I get error:

```
adb install -r my_app-release.apk
Performing Push Install
my_app-release: 1 file pushed. 4.5 MB/s (9219518 bytes in 1.946s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/my_app-release.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

P.S. I sign new version of my with same private key as previous version of my app (in Google Play). When I sign APK I select the next signature versions:
`V1 (jar signature)` **AND** `V2(Full APK signature)`

Comment: You need to remove the old version.

Comment: I can't remove old version. Because I try to update version from Google Play

Comment: You can do `adb uninstall path_to_my_sign.apk`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891848/install-failed-update-incompatible-when-i-try-to-install-compiled-apk-on-device

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The old version(in Google Play) of my app was signed by key **NOT EQUALS** to key that I signed new version of my app.