# Release app but got error INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, key, store

I am facing an issue related to the key store.

Step:

- Install app from google play store (version name 1.0.0 version code 10)
- Build new apk and replace install (version name 1.1.0 version code 11)

I got the message:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package package name signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]

I guarantee that the key store is correct

Has anyone had problems like me?
Please help or give me some advice
Thank you

Comment: The most probable reason is that the app is not installed for the current user: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32702041/2936153

Comment: uninstall previously installed build, may be this is debug build without signature

Comment: make sure you are uploading the correct apk file. It should be prod release.

Comment: Currently if we installed app from google play store, after that we make install to update by command then get that error.