# I cant solve Node.js installDebug error.What should i do?

Tags: node.js, react-native

everyone, I'm a student in the Computer Science department and I try to learn to react from Udemy. I stack on this problem. I tried some solutions but they didn't work for me. Sorry about bad English.

```
`PS C:\Windows\system32> cd C:\Users\Mozgor\Desktop\project\helloWorldProject
PS C:\Users\Mozgor\Desktop\project\helloWorldProject> react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:installDebug
06:26:09 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
06:26:10 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on '192.168.135.101:5555' : EOF hit. Read: -1
06:26:10 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Google Nexus 5X - 7.1.1' for app:debug
06:26:10 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device '192.168.135.101:5555'
06:26:10 D/Device: Uploading file onto device '192.168.135.101:5555'
06:26:10 D/ddms: Reading file permision of C:\Users\Mozgor\Desktop\project\helloWorldProject\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
06:26:10 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
06:26:11 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '192.168.135.101:5555' : EOF hit. Read: -1
06:26:11 V/ddms: execute: returning

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
27 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 25 up-to-date
Unable to install C:\Users\Mozgor\Desktop\project\helloWorldProject\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.helloworldproject signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!
        at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installRemotePackage(Device.java:1063)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:903)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:881)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:870)
        at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:126)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.install(InstallVariantTask.java:179)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.install(InstallVariantTask.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:702)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:669)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:401)        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:390)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:373)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:210)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.helloworldproject signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 7s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Mozgor\Desktop\project\helloWorldProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\Mozgor\Desktop\project\helloWorldProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
    at C:\Users\Mozgor\Desktop\project\helloWorldProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Mozgor\Desktop\project\helloWorldProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:9)`
```

I used React Native one month ago for my university project, but I used a different version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Uninstall the existing APK from your device before compiling. [INSTALL\_FAILED\_UPDATE\_INCOMPATIBLE when I try to install compiled .apk on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891848/install-failed-update-incompatible-when-i-try-to-install-compiled-apk-on-device)

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with installation of apk on your device and not the node as it is stating that `INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE`.

It means you already have a copy of the app on your device where you are trying to install the app.

So, first execute the command too uninstall your existing build from device:

```
adb uninstall your.package.identifier
```

Then again try to run the app with command like

```
react-native run-android
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: When i opened my computer int his morning suddenly it worked still thx :)

Comment: Good to hear that.