# Flutter -- java.lang.RuntimeException: at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3 (AsyncQueue.java)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, background, release

**Problem:**

This is my output:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3 (AsyncQueue.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$jx84dqgUsF4ojecSMurRqFLFD1Y.run (-.java)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7050)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
Caused by: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: 
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.getResult (zzw.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel.lambda$runBidiStreamingRpc$0 (FirestoreChannel.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel.lambda$runBidiStreamingRpc$0$FirestoreChannel (FirestoreChannel.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.-$$Lambda$FirestoreChannel$ThFui-hvcsrVGYxlBtcTH5vVbvE.onComplete (-.java:6)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run (zzi.java:21)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:459)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run (AsyncQueue.java:15)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzz.run (zzz.java:17)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0 (ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0$ThrottledForwardingExecutor (ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$ThrottledForwardingExecutor$MfIJbVuxZtLwosAgPzPA-cU66Ko.run (-.java:4)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: 
  at java.lang.Enum$1.create (Enum.java:272)
  at java.lang.Enum$1.create (Enum.java:262)
  at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get (BasicLruCache.java:58)
  at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants (Enum.java:289)
  at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared (Class.java:2424)
  at java.util.EnumSet.getUniverse (EnumSet.java:407)
  at java.util.EnumSet.noneOf (EnumSet.java:109)
  at java.util.EnumSet.of (EnumSet.java:235)
  at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.<clinit> (OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:91)
  at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.forTarget (OkHttpChannelBuilder.java)
  at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget (OkHttpChannelProvider.java)
  at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget (OkHttpChannelProvider.java)
  at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget (ManagedChannelBuilder.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.initChannel (GrpcCallProvider.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6 (GrpcCallProvider.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6$GrpcCallProvider (GrpcCallProvider.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.-$$Lambda$GrpcCallProvider$SCD5iiibQ8l4haiO8ofSfE0wIJg.call (-.java:2)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzz.run (zzz.java:4)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0 (ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0$ThrottledForwardingExecutor (ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$ThrottledForwardingExecutor$MfIJbVuxZtLwosAgPzPA-cU66Ko.run (-.java:4)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod (Class.java:2069)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod (Class.java:2047)
  at java.lang.Enum$1.create (Enum.java:268)
  at java.lang.Enum$1.create (Enum.java:262)
  at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get (BasicLruCache.java:58)
  at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants (Enum.java:289)
  at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared (Class.java:2424)
  at java.util.EnumSet.getUniverse (EnumSet.java:407)
  at java.util.EnumSet.noneOf (EnumSet.java:109)
  at java.util.EnumSet.of (EnumSet.java:235)
  at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.<clinit> (OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:91)
  at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.forTarget (OkHttpChannelBuilder.java)
  at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget (OkHttpChannelProvider.java)
  at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget (OkHttpChannelProvider.java)
  at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget (ManagedChannelBuilder.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.initChannel (GrpcCallProvider.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6 (GrpcCallProvider.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6$GrpcCallProvider (GrpcCallProvider.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.-$$Lambda$GrpcCallProvider$SCD5iiibQ8l4haiO8ofSfE0wIJg.call (-.java:2)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzz.run (zzz.java:4)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0 (ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0$ThrottledForwardingExecutor (ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
  at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$ThrottledForwardingExecutor$MfIJbVuxZtLwosAgPzPA-cU66Ko.run (-.java:4)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

If I want to open the APK:

1. the app opens perfectly
2. the screen is black
3. the app goes in the background

---

**Notes:**

If I run `flutter run --release` the app opens perfectly but it also shows an error:

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\Flutter\StudioProjects\nomadnet2\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.apps.social_circle signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

If I run: `flutter run` it works perfectly

---

**I already tried:**

1. upgrade the packages
2. install flutter SDK again
3. update flutter

I also tried more things but I don't know them anymore

---

Please help me!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891848/install-failed-update-incompatible-when-i-try-to-install-compiled-apk-on-device

Comment: Do you have two user profiles/accounts in your device? If so you have to uninstall old version from both profiles/accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the solution that worked for me is to register all packages from scratch**

---

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete your previus APK in

> C:\Users\Flutter\StudioProjects\nomadnet2\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk

Then use the command

> flutter clean

And pub get your pubspect.yaml

and try to run the release version again

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Delete your previously installed app in your phone or emulator, and run release again, probably is because a different sign key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue.
What I did was:-

Go to phone settings -> under apps section -> search for application name -> remove for all users.
This worked for my case, just try it out :)