# Android: Package parsing error

Tags: android

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 which is updated with Jelly Bean and rooted. I copy and paste my application into the system/app folder and try to install the app by tapping it from this folder, but I get "PACKAGE PARSING ERROR".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pest`? you meant `paste` i assume. `Double-click`? Nevertheless, give some details about the `apk`(how and where was it created).

Comment: Thanks For Replay, I develop app whose work is install and uninstall another app by giving path of apk and and package name respectively, This app successfully install if I am installing it from sdcard and it also work in another tab or phone but when i put this apk in system/app folder by ES File Explorer and try to install it then give errors

Answer (score 1):

It means there is some error in the apk created. 
Is this apk you wrote? If so,

1. can you check the manifest if it follows the structure defined in
   [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)
2. can you try running it in Emulator or other phone
   and see if it reproduces just to make sure its not a problem with
   the current phone. More details on the error can help in identifying
   the issue.
3. Did you rename your apk and installed with a previous
   name? Check this out:
   ["Parse Error : There is a problem parsing the package" while installing Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android)