# Installing apk file fails on 2.3 device only when downloaded over the air or installed from an email attachment

Tags: android, eclipse, galaxy

I'm hoping someone will be able to help me with this download issue I have been struggling with.

I have written an android application in eclipse (version indigo) with target build 2.3.3 signed and uploaded the application to our download site.

The signing certificate .jks file that we are using only expires in the year 2100 in August.

The application downloads, installs and runs on most of our test devices (listed below) except the samsung galaxy ace devices(also listed below)

The devices that were able to download and install the application successfully were the following:

- Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 P6200 (running OS 3.2)
- Galaxy S3 (running OS 4.1.1)
- Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 P5100 (running OS 4.1.1)
- Galaxy Tab 3 8.0 (running OS 4.2.2)

The two devices that failed downloading over the air were the following

- Galaxy Ace GT-S5830 (running OS 2.3.3)
- Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i (running OS 2.3.7)

When installing from our download site or via an email attachment I receive the generic 'Parse Error - There is a problem parsing the package'

I have been able to successfully install the application onto the two Ace devices by the following methods:

- Manually copying the file onto the sd card via the usb cable and installing it from there.
- Using the adb commands to successfully install the application via usb cable
- The generic 'debug to device' in eclipse

I have done some research and have tried the following fixes which have not worked:

- Removing the min SDK attribute from the manifest file.
- Rebuilding the project with a target SDK of 2.2
- Trying a brand new project with the default 'hello world' screen as the only class in the
  project and trying with a target build of 2.2 and 2.3.3.

*Edit:* All the devices have been set to allow downloading from unknown sources.

Is it possible that I have missed a basic step when going through the signing process or is there something specific that I need to allow the application to be downloaded and installed over the air on 2.3.3/2.3.7 devices?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 0):

may be you should try to enable the unknown sources in your device. go to Menu-->Settings-->Applications-->Enable the Unknown sources

Comment: Thanks for the response. I forgot add that to the list of things tried. The device was set to allow downloading from unknown sources and unfortunately was still not working.

Comment: may be you should see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android

Comment: Thanks again for the responses. Im checking that clear cache option now.

Comment: I did see that post before and tried creating a new blank application just in case I had changed the name of the apk or had targeted the wrong build but unfortunately it did not work either.

Comment: I have tested clearing the memory cache and unfortunately it did exactly the same thing and received the parse error. I then also tried a full factory reset on the phone and also received the same parse error message.