# Android Parsing the Package

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

My application works fine before after i change something in code. APK not installing on mobile shows error parsing package. works fine on emulator.
Please Help cant understand what is wrong.

Here is my LogCat

```
06-20 12:36:21.050: D/AndroidRuntime(868): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
06-20 12:36:21.093: D/AndroidRuntime(868): CheckJNI is ON
06-20 12:36:28.621: D/AndroidRuntime(871): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
06-20 12:36:28.621: D/AndroidRuntime(871): CheckJNI is ON
06-20 12:36:33.411: D/AndroidRuntime(868): --- registering native functions ---
06-20 12:36:33.591: D/AndroidRuntime(871): --- registering native functions ---
06-20 12:36:49.554: D/AndroidRuntime(868): Shutting down VM
06-20 12:36:49.621: D/dalvikvm(868): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-20 12:36:51.994: D/dalvikvm(249): GC_EXPLICIT freed 77 objects / 8008 bytes in 709ms
06-20 12:36:52.611: D/PackageParser(72): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl68317.tmp
06-20 12:36:56.851: D/dalvikvm(72): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 16168 objects / 946008 bytes in 1355ms
06-20 12:36:58.200: I/PackageManager(72): Removing non-system package:com.android.msfm
06-20 12:36:58.200: I/ActivityManager(72): Force stopping package com.android.msfm uid=10037
06-20 12:36:58.706: I/Process(72): Sending signal. PID: 860 SIG: 9
06-20 12:36:59.412: I/WindowManager(72): WIN DEATH: Window{4504d470 com.android.msfm/com.android.msfm.LoginActivity paused=false}
06-20 12:36:59.775: I/UsageStats(72): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.android.msfm
06-20 12:37:00.384: W/InputManagerService(72): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 860 uid 10037
06-20 12:37:03.611: D/PackageManager(72): Scanning package com.android.msfm
06-20 12:37:03.611: I/PackageManager(72): Package com.android.msfm codePath changed from /data/app/com.android.msfm-1.apk to /data/app/com.android.msfm-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
06-20 12:37:03.642: I/PackageManager(72): /data/app/com.android.msfm-2.apk changed; unpacking
06-20 12:37:03.820: D/installd(34): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.android.msfm-2.apk' ---
06-20 12:37:10.691: D/dalvikvm(884): DexOpt: load 1115ms, verify 3598ms, opt 136ms
06-20 12:37:10.855: D/installd(34): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.android.msfm-2.apk' (success) ---
06-20 12:37:10.861: W/PackageManager(72): Code path for pkg : com.android.msfm changing from /data/app/com.android.msfm-1.apk to /data/app/com.android.msfm-2.apk
06-20 12:37:10.861: W/PackageManager(72): Resource path for pkg : com.android.msfm changing from /data/app/com.android.msfm-1.apk to /data/app/com.android.msfm-2.apk
06-20 12:37:10.873: I/ActivityManager(72): Force stopping package com.android.msfm uid=10037
06-20 12:37:10.881: D/PackageManager(72):   Services: com.android.msfm.GCMIntentService
06-20 12:37:10.881: D/PackageManager(72):   Receivers: com.android.msfm.AlarmReceiver com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver
06-20 12:37:10.901: D/PackageManager(72):   Activities: com.android.msfm.SplashActivity com.android.msfm.LoginActivity com.android.msfm.DashBoard com.android.msfm.RetailerList com.android.msfm.SelectRetailer com.android.msfm.AddNewRetailer com.android.msfm.RetailerDetails com.android.msfm.CustomDialogBox com.android.msfm.TakeOrderStock com.android.msfm.TakeStockOrder com.android.msfm.Order com.android.msfm.TakeOrder com.android.msfm.TodaysMap com.android.msfm.ShopSelection com.android.msfm.ArrangeShop com.android.msfm.MapRoute com.android.msfm.SelectRoute com.android.msfm.NotificationDetails com.android.msfm.Notifications com.android.msfm.PendingOrders com.android.msfm.DisplayRetailers com.android.msfm.SelectTempRetailers com.android.msfm.SelectPendingRejectRetailer com.android.msfm.DisplayRoutes com.android.msfm.SelectPendingRejectRoute com.android.msfm.SelectTempRoutes com.android.msfm.SyncPopUpMenu com.android.msfm.OrderView com.android.msfm.DisplaySo com.android.msfm.TempItemDeleteDialog com.android.msfm.ProductDetails
06-20 12:37:10.901: D/PackageManager(72):   Permissions: com.android.msfm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
06-20 12:37:11.226: I/installd(34): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.android.msfm-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.android.msfm-2.apk@classes.dex
06-20 12:37:11.226: D/PackageManager(72): New package installed in /data/app/com.android.msfm-2.apk
06-20 12:37:11.250: W/PackageManager(72): Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
06-20 12:37:11.271: W/PackageManager(72): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x1be45)
06-20 12:37:11.271: W/PackageManager(72): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
06-20 12:37:11.281: W/PackageManager(72): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
06-20 12:37:11.322: W/PackageManager(72): Unknown permission com.android.providers.im.permission.READ_ONLY in package com.google.android.apps.maps
06-20 12:37:11.322: W/PackageManager(72): Unknown permission com.google.android.pushmessaging.permission.RECEIVE in package com.google.android.apps.maps
06-20 12:37:11.601: I/ActivityManager(72): Force stopping package com.android.msfm uid=10037
06-20 12:37:11.951: D/dalvikvm(207): GC_EXPLICIT freed 273 objects / 13392 bytes in 222ms
06-20 12:37:11.971: D/dalvikvm(72): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11568 objects / 622760 bytes in 270ms
06-20 12:37:16.611: W/RecognitionManagerService(72): no available voice recognition services found
06-20 12:37:18.504: D/dalvikvm(72): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9198 objects / 479608 bytes in 335ms
06-20 12:37:19.193: I/installd(34): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.android.msfm-1.apk@classes.dex
06-20 12:37:19.251: D/AndroidRuntime(871): Shutting down VM
06-20 12:37:19.271: D/dalvikvm(871): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-20 12:37:19.301: I/AndroidRuntime(871): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
06-20 12:37:20.191: D/AndroidRuntime(889): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
06-20 12:37:20.191: D/AndroidRuntime(889): CheckJNI is ON
06-20 12:37:20.604: D/AndroidRuntime(889): --- registering native functions ---
06-20 12:37:21.772: I/ActivityManager(72): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.msfm/.SplashActivity }
06-20 12:37:21.971: D/AndroidRuntime(889): Shutting down VM
06-20 12:37:22.091: D/jdwp(889): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
06-20 12:37:22.091: D/dalvikvm(889): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-20 12:37:23.361: I/ActivityManager(72): Start proc com.android.msfm for activity com.android.msfm/.SplashActivity: pid=896 uid=10037 gids={3003}
06-20 12:37:27.181: I/ActivityManager(72): Displayed activity com.android.msfm/.SplashActivity: 4754 ms (total 4754 ms)
06-20 12:37:28.596: D/dalvikvm(193): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2469 objects / 127224 bytes in 9180ms
06-20 12:37:28.841: I/ActivityManager(72): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.android.msfm/.LoginActivity }
06-20 12:37:29.400: D/dalvikvm(896): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1250 objects / 84880 bytes in 137ms
06-20 12:37:33.232: W/ResourceType(72): Skipping entry 0x7f040000 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
06-20 12:37:33.241: W/ResourceType(72): Skipping entry 0x7f040001 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
06-20 12:37:34.261: I/ActivityManager(72): Displayed activity com.android.msfm/.LoginActivity: 5343 ms (total 5343 ms)
06-20 12:37:41.022: D/dalvikvm(391): GC_EXPLICIT freed 105 objects / 6528 bytes in 1292ms
06-20 12:37:45.201: D/dalvikvm(370): GC_EXPLICIT freed 85 objects / 4120 bytes in 418ms
06-20 12:37:49.971: D/dalvikvm(207): GC_EXPLICIT freed 664 objects / 37800 bytes in 171ms
```

Comment: Have a look here [Parse Error : There is a problem parsing the package” while installing Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android)

Comment: I found that APK installing via USB but when try to install from gmail application it gives package cannot parse Error

Answer (score 0):

check projects.properties  file and set target.
target=android-4

Comment: i set to android-4 but it give errors to my jdbc connection class file