# Android Deploy Parse Error but Works on Genymotion

Tags: java, android, genymotion, deploying

I'm trying to deploy my first test app, but it's giving me a *Parse Error* - `There was a problem while parsing the package`.

Whilst, it executes fine on my Genymotion virtual device. It's the normal first "Hello World" app you'd get automatically.

Also, it executes on both virtual devices of Samsung Galaxy S3 and Samsung Galaxy S5 but not on real devices such as Samsung Galaxy S5 and Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1.

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lovely"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Main activity:**

```
package com.example.lovely;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.lovely.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Appreciate any assistance, thank you.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android

Comment: i've checked that, it didn't work for me. or i didn't do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting as signed rather than unsigned fixed it. Not sure why, my phone and tablet both accept " unknown sources " feel free to explain why this has hapenned