# Android - Parsing error of the package when installing apk in device

Tags: android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, apk

When installing apk to the device i got error saying `Parse error: There was a problem a parsing the package` but I could run in the emulator.
Properties during generate of APK:

```
Minimum Android version: Android 5.0(API Level 21-Lollipop)
Target Android version: Android 6.0(API Level 23-Marshmallow)

Target Framework: Android 8.1(Oreo)
```

I will be installing the apk in Android 6.0 device.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android

Comment: this is my first apk generated and got error

Comment: did it generate apk without any error?

Comment: Hi, @Jen143, please read [this](https://www.problogbooster.com/2015/09/fix-there-was-a-problem-parsing-the-package-solve-parse-error.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: @SupunLiyanaarachchi yes. It generate apk without error

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT yes i have done with it

Comment: @Jen143, solved?

Comment: No. It didn't help at all. Same issue

Comment: share screenshot of your android project-> properties->  "android option"  .