# How to solve parse error while installing android app?

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm creating an app using Xamarin.Forms . 
This app runs correctly on emulator (android version 7.1) in Visual Studio 2017.
But gives "Parse Error : There was problem parsing the package." while installing it on my phone (Android version : 5.1).
Can anyone please help in solving this issue ????
Thanks in advance !!!!

ToastService Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace XamService.Droid.Services
{
    [Service(Exported = true , Name = "XamService.ToastService")]
    class ToastService : Service
    {
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        [return: GeneratedEnum]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "This is a toast from service !", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

    }
}
```

ServiceCaller class

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using XamService.Interfaces;
using XamService.Droid.Services;
using XamService.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly:Dependency(typeof(ServiceCaller))]
namespace XamService.Droid
{
    class ServiceCaller : Activity, ICaller
    {
        public void serviceCaller()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(ToastService));
            Forms.Context.StartService(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

AndoridManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0" 
          package="com.companyname.XamService" 
          android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="XamService.Android">
        <service android:name="ToastService" enabled="true"></service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [this](https://techxoom.com/fix-parse-error-in-android-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android).

Comment: Previously it did not  have background services in android and worked fine. After adding background service in android, this error is coming...

Comment: `<service android:name="ToastService" enabled="true"></service>`, you added this manually？Try to delete the bin and obj folder, and delete the app on your phone, reinstall it.

Comment: Yes manually. OK I'll try the steps mentioned.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT I tried, didn't work

Comment: Try use adb command to install the apk. Also, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3268903/8632294).

Comment: I was able to solve the issue. I removed <service></service> tags from AndroidManifest.xml and just added [Service] above every service class. Thank you for all suggestions though !!!