# How to resolve parsing package error while installing apk file in android Nougat

Tags: android, apk

I working on installing APK file present in the device programmatically. Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        askForPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,0x4);
        askForPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,0x3);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.install);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent();
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ExtractedApks/Airtel_TV_tv.accedo.airtel.wynk.apk"));
                //Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/Airtel_TV_tv.accedo.airtel.wynk.apk"));
                intent.setDataAndType(photoURI, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(intent);



            }
        });

    }

    private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
            }
        } else {
            return;
            //Toast.makeText(this, "" + permission + " is already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


}


**MainActivity** - create a button to install apk file store in external memory.
```

/**************************************************************************/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.installapkfiles">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Manifest** - File provider to enable other application to install. 
/****************************************************************************/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<!--    <cache-path name="cache" path="." />
    <files-path name="files" path="."/>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>-->

    <external-path path="Android/data/${applicationId}/" name="files_root" />
    <root-path name="root" path="/" />
    <!--<external-path path="." name="external_storage_root" />-->

</paths>
```

**File_provider** - File provider to point external storage.
/****************************************************************************/

```
I'm selecting package installer for installing the application. But, it is poping  "There was a problem while parsing the package".
How to resolve this error.

Thanks & Regards,
Gowtham M
```

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Parse Error : There is a problem parsing the package" while installing Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
1.File may be downloaded incompletely.
2.Application might be not suitable for your hardware or OS version.
3.Due to security issue settings
4.Corrupted APK file.
```

To solve this error

```
  1.Go to the settings
  2.Scroll down & select option “security.”
  3.Check on the option “Unknown sources.”
```

To enable USB debugging:

```
1. Go to the settings >> Scroll down then, at last, you will see
        option “About device” select it.
2. Look for option “build number.” Tap on “Build number” for 7 times.
3. You will see a message “you are now a developer.” Once you enable to
4.  go back to settings Choose “Developer options.” Tick mark "USB
            debugging."
```