# Parse error at Installation of APK file

Tags: android

My apk file format is like this:

```
xxxx-debug.apk
xx-xxx-debug-xxx-1.0.1.apk
```

I can download the apk files but I cannot install them. I'm facing the following error:

```
Parse error
    There was a problem while parsing the package.
```

Code used for Installation:

```
protected void install(String fileName) {
    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(install);
}
```

When the apk file are downloaded, a number is appended at the end of the file e.g. `some.apk` becomes `some-1.apk`.

What I have tried/checked so far:

- check on the option “Unknown sources.”
- uses-permission `android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"`
- android device version is 5.0.1
- apk files are not corrupted because I've managed to install it in a different way

Answer (score 0):

Please try disabling instant run and then generate apk.It will work.Hope it helps.

Comment: And also remove previous APKs from device.

Comment: I've tried all that unfortunately still same result. :-(

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue previously. This is how I debugged it.
First, install the APK through terminal
`adb install path_to_your_app/name_of_your_app.apk`
if you get error message: 
`adb: failed to install name_of_your_app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries`
this means that the architecture that you are building mismatches with the emulator architecture.

The way I fixed this issue is by forcing the build architecture in build.gradle

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'x86_64'
            }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and for me the issue was the Minimum API Level. I had the minimum API too high, which means some devices were not able to use the app. In Unity go to: Player Settings > Other Settings > Identification >

Minimum API Level: This should be set to the minimum which for me Android 4.4 'KitKat' (API level 19)
Maximum API Level: This should be set to the maximum according to Google, see link https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk

Comment: Nobody said anything about Unity.