# Share flutter app as APK which works on real devices

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I want to build APK from the flutter project and share it to someone to review. I followed the docs, but the problem is when he tries to open the APK he gets

> "there was a problem parsing the package"

I tried it on another device and gets

> "App not installed"

I think the problem is in the APK file, So how I can build a correct APK that works on real devices?

I keep the name of the file "app.apk" does that matter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

from the Flutter [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android), to build an APK from the command line:

Run `flutter build apk`

*(The flutter build command defaults to --release.)*

This command results in an APK file:

```
[project]/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
```

take note of the path and ask name(**app-release.apk**)

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to debug why the apk not running on physical device, install this app https://fbflipper.com/ on your system, and connect your mobile device though a usb cable, now when you run the apk, on the flipper app you will receive crash report that will help you understand why your app is crashing!