App update issue and getting error message "There was a problem while parsing the package"
I want to implement app update features in my android application so I put APK file on my ftp server which is downloading successfully in my device at Documents/Apk/ now after downloading the apk app trying to startactivity for update app then I am getting popup message "There was a problem while parsing the package".
I have checked manually updating the app and its successfully updating the app.
I have created both the debug apk with different version and downloading upper version apk.
Below is my app_paths.xml file placed under res/xml/
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="Documents/Apk/" /> <!-- Relative path from external storage -->
</paths>

I have added provider in manifest file like below
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.code.app.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/app_paths" />
        </provider>

I have added permissions in manifest file
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

below is my code from which I am updating the app
public static void installApk(Context context, File apkFile) {
        try {
            if (apkFile.exists() && apkFile.canRead()) {
                // Log the full path of the APK file to ensure it's correct
                Log.d("APK Path", apkFile.getAbsolutePath());

                // Generate URI for the APK file using FileProvider
                Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                        "com.code.app.fileprovider", apkFile);
                //Uri apkUri = Uri.parse("content://com.code.app.fileprovider/external_files/Documents/Apk/app_build31.apk");

                // Log the generated URI for debugging
                Log.d("APK URI", apkUri.toString());

                // Intent to install APK
                Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                installIntent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // Required flag for non-Activity contexts
                installIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION); // Grant read URI permission

                // For Android 8.0+ (Oreo and above), check if "Install Unknown Apps" permission is required
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    if (!context.getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
                        // If permission is not granted, redirect to the settings screen
                        Log.e("Enable", "Install Unknown Apps' for this app and retry.");
                        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES);
                        settingsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
                        settingsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // Ensure this flag is added
                        context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(settingsIntent);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                // Start the install APK activity
                context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(installIntent);

            } else {
                Log.e("Install Error", "APK file does not exist.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Install Error", "Error installing APK: ", e);
        }
    }


Check if any of these answers work for you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1501361/13887525

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59281007/13887525



Thanks @Christophy for your reply. I have checked both the answers but not worked in m case
